# High voltage sensing - voltage to current converter

Tags: sensing, high-side

Hi i need to sense the voltage of a floating load anbd TI suggest placing a sort of common emitter amplifier as shown below:
[image]

however im not sure how they calculate the sense voltage:
[image]

How is the equation derived considering the voltage divider of R16 and R17 is not referenced to ground?

Comment: Where does the floating load resistor fit into your circuit?

Comment: across the vbus+ and vbus-

Comment: I think they've over-complicated the formula with hFE when it isn't really needed to be accounted for.